# Inserting a record into a database with looping foreign keys

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, relational-database, entity-relationship

I have this relationship:

[image]

Where `CurrentVersionID` points to the current active version of the game.

In `ArcadeGameVersion` the `GameID` property points to the associated `ArcadeGame` record.

Problem is, I can't insert either record:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ArcadeGame_ArcadeGameVersions". The conflict occurred in database "Scirra", table "dbo.ArcadeGameVersions", column 'ID'.
```

Is this a badly formed data structure?  Otherwise what is the best solution to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems badly formed. I can not see why you need this circular reference.
I would use only one table ArcadeGame with additional fields CurrentVersion and UploadDate.
You can query it based on UploadDate for example, up to your needs. If you explain what you want from that db, answer could be more specific.

Comment: How would you structure it?

Answer (score 0):

This structure can work if you need it to be this way.. assuming the IDs are identity fields, I believe you will need to do this in 5 steps:

1. Insert an ArcadeGame record with a null value for CurrentVersionId
2. Determine the ID value of the record just added, using a statement like: `SELECT @arcadeGameId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()`
3. Insert an ArcadeGameVersion record, setting the GameID to the value determined in the previous step
4. Determine the ID value of the record just added (again using SCOPE_IDENTITY())
5. Update the ArcadeGame record (where the ID matches that determined in step 2) and set the CurrentVersionId to the value determined in the previous step.

You will (most likely) want to do the above within a transaction.

If the IDs aren't identity fields and you know the values ahead of time, you can mostly follow the same steps as above but skip the SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() steps.